# AS3 only app breaks when I compile w/ adobe sdk, works when I compile w/ apache sdk (same adobe sdk)

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, adobe

something strange happens when I switch between the adobe sdk (3.90.1210), and the apache sdk (which includes the same adobe sdk (3.90.1210)

one would think that there should be no differences when I make this switch, as my app is AS3 only, no flex references, and the underlying sdks are the same

the app builds and runs under both sdks, but about half of my images just dont show up when I run under the adobe sdk

so I dig down and I can see that the bitmap data objects that dont show up all have their HxW set to zero, the others have it set to proper HxW

the thing is, this has worked fine for a long time under the various adobe sdks, and something in the apache sdk fixes the problem, would like to understand it

meanwhile the wierdness in the images has something to do with having been flattened or not during production... images are all pngs, imported into flash and compiled to a swc, then merged into code

not a graphics guy, was hoping I wouldnt have to become one... have poked around and cant figure that side of it out...

suggestions?

one thought is to go back thru our hundreds of images and flatten (unflatten? whatever) them all with some photoshop batch process... this would not be fun

or I could stick w/ the apache sdk... which makes me a little nervous in that I have no idea what magic it's bringing

thoughts? anyone else seeing this?

thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific. Adobe has had three standard SDKs for Flash development: Flash, AIR, and Flex <= 4.6. I assume you are referring to Flex, but you mention version numbers that match the current AIR SDK. Regardless, why would you want to use Adobe Flex at this point? It's development ceased roughly 2 years ago when it was donated to Apache, ending with Flex 4.6. Apache has continued development and is now on Flex 4.11 with Flex 4.12 due out in the next 90 days or so.

Comment: yes, was talking about the adobe AIR sdk -- was using it because I'm not using any flex, project is AS3 only, so why mess w/ the flex compiler at all? but, then, had the problem described above... so at this point my questions are two: why is the adobe AIR sdk breaking half my images, and, why is the apache flex sdk doing anything different, given that they're both the same AIR sdk anyway? thanks

Comment: I think you are confused here. The Flex SDK has **nothing** to do with the AIR SDK. At all. The Flex SDK can be used in an AIR app and Apache generally installs the latest AIR SDK alongside it, but that is it. Flex is a GUI SDK where as AIR is a runtime SDK. Apache has not developed any part of the AIR SDK. The only reason this could possibly be happening is that your project **is** using Flex classes. Search your project for anything saying `spark` or `mx`. Odds are you are at least importing a Flex class.

Comment: ok thanks for your help... so, lets see... would it be correct to say that the flex sdk depends on the air sdk, in that the flex sdk creates a runtime version of the all the ui stuff, and the air sdk takes it the rest of the way to a compiled app? and so what apache ships is a stack: the current air sdk (by adobe) along w/ the flex sdk (by apache). it's that sdk that is the same in my two cases, all by itself in one case, and along w/ the flex compiler in the other.

Comment: all that said, I agree if the two build configs dont behave the same, there must be some flex reference in there somewhere that changes the game. just that I cant find it. will keep looking.

Comment: It may be that Apache Flex is still using the older AS compiler, there are two version of AIR one with a newer AS compiler, one with the older. It's possible you discovered a bug with the Adobes's new compiler.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid stretching out the comments on the main question further, I'll throw this into an answer.

There are three **official** SDKs for Flash development. There are several others (like Starling) which have no affiliation with Adobe, so we won't count those.

1. **Flash SDK** - This is the basis for all things Flash and is developed *solely* by Adobe. Your core classes (`DisplayObject`, `Object`, `Number`, `System`, etc) are all found within this SDK. No matter what you are building for, every Flash application **must** include this SDK.
2. **Flex SDK** - Flex is a GUI framework originally developed by Adobe. After v4.6, roughly two years ago, Adobe donated the framework to Apache. Since that time, Apache has been developing the framework with fairly consistent development. We are currently at 4.11 with 4.12 due out in the coming months. This framework is also open-source, so it is partially community developed, partially Apache developed. There are two main different GUI frameworks in Flex: MX and Spark. MX is no longer in development, while Spark is. You should not mix components from the two.
3. **AIR SDK** - This is the Adobe Integrated Runtime. AIR allows you to run Flash apps as native apps on various platforms. The AIR SDK is the bridge between Flash and the native platform and nothing more. It is developed **solely** by Adobe and is closed-source. Apache has no part in this project, other than Adobe's promise to keep supporting Flex and MXML for the foreseeable future.

So with those things in mind, let's look at how they interact. As I said, the Flash SDK is included in all Flash apps. The AIR and Flex SDKs are built in ActionScript 3 (Flex is NOT built in MXML) using the classes found within the Flash SDK. The AIR SDK is used to build a native application, and that is the only time it should be used. The Flex SDK is a set of GUI components that make building interfaces easy and can be used in both web and AIR applications.

The Flex SDK can exist without the AIR SDK and the AIR SDK can exist without the Flex SDK. There is absolutely no reliance between the two. For the sake of unity, the Flex and AIR SDKs are generally combined into a single folder. This *does not* mean they are the same SDK or related in any way, just that this is how the SDKs are loaded. This was an ease-of-use decision by Adobe years ago when they still developed Flex.

So if your AS3 project is using the same AIR SDK version are your Flex app and you are getting compiler errors when you compile AS3, there **must** be something Flex in your project. Maybe a Formatter or the RPC classes used to make SOAP calls). You need to find that and get rid of that or import the correct SWC file from the Flex SDK, assuming it isn't a GUI component.